# Is there any difference between "jetzt schon" and "schon jetzt"?

Tags: word-order, particle

Are "jetzt schon" and "schon jetzt" interchangeable? Is one more commonly used than the other? Is one more "formal"?

For example:

> - Ich freue mich **jetzt schon** auf das Wochenende.
> - Wir freuen uns **schon jetzt** auf Ihre Bewerbung.

> Europaminister Bek: „Wir können der Ukraine **schon jetzt / jetzt schon** den Kandidatenstatus geben“ ?

[Here](https://de.bab.la/woerterbuch/deutsch-englisch/jetzt-schon) you can find many examples, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions mean exactly the same thing, and both versions have been used about equally often over the last 200 years. But since about 2005, the frequency of *»jetzt schon«* has increased dramatically (while *»schon jetzt«* has also increased, but much more slowly).

[image: Google Ngram: schon jetzt, jetzt schon]
Source: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=schon%20jetzt%2C%20jetzt%20schon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cschon%20jetzt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjetzt%20schon%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cschon%20jetzt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjetzt%20schon%3B%2Cc0)